# Problem with disabling attribute by getting elements by class name

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple `input` tags like below:

`<input type="checkbox" class="check" disabled id="identifier">`

and:

`<input type="checkbox" class="check" disabled>`

I'd like to disable `disabled` attribute.

If i do it like this:

`document.getElementById("identifier").removeAttribute('disabled');`

Everything seems to work fine. However when i try to disable this attribute by getting elements by class name, the elements won't disable. I tried following examples:

`document.getElementsByClassName("check").removeAttribute('disabled');`

and:

`document.querySelectorAll(".check").removeAttribute('disabled');`

Both examples won't work. Could you please spot what am I doing wrong? I would really appreciate some help ;). Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need a loop to remove the attribute from all the elements in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getElementsByClassName and querySelectorAll returns array...

```
document.getElementsByClassName("check")[0].removeAttribute('disabled')
```

This would work for the first element... If you want all elements you need to loop through them.

Comment: Now I understand. Thank you.